# Show that if $n$ is a positive integer then $\binom{2n}{2} = 2\binom{n}{2} + n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $\binom{2n}{2} = 2\binom{n}{2} + n^2$
I went through my textbook and found nothing about this, also do not remember ever doing anything like this in class so i am completely lost on it, no idea where to start.

Just need some direction on where to start and the things i would need to do to prove this.

Comment: Do you mean $\binom{2n}{2} = 2\binom n2 + n^2$?

Comment: yes, didnt know how to format that, thank you

Comment: You do it like `$\binom{2n}{2} = 2\binom{n}{2} + n^2$`. See for instance [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more formatting guidance. Anyways, it should be pretty straight-forward to just insert the definition of $\binom{p}{r}$ and check that the two expressions you get are equal. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4):

Throwing this in for completeness:

How many ways are there to choose $2$ objects from $2n$ total objects? Either both are chosen from the first $n$ objects, both are chosen from the last $n$ objects, or one is chosen from the first $n$ and one is chosen from the last $n$ objects.

The number of ways to choose $k$ things from $m$ total objects is $\binom{m}{k}$. This gives the identity without any manipulations.

Comment: I Was 2 minutes late

Answer (score 2):

You can prove it by induction.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=2$:**

$\binom{2\cdot2}{2}=2\binom{2}{2}+2^2$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\binom{2n}{2}=2\binom{n}{2}+n^2$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\binom{2(n+1)}{2}=$

$\binom{2n+2}{2}=$

$\color\red{\binom{2n}{2}}+(2n+1)(2n+2)/2-n(2n-1)=$

$\color\red{2\binom{n}{2}+n^2}+(2n+1)(2n+2)/2-n(2n-1)=$

$2\binom{n+1}{2}+(n+1)^2$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\binom{N}{2}=\frac{N^2 - N}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Start with definition of the binomial coefficient and compare both LHS with RHS…

Start with: $\binom{2n}{2} = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n - 2)! 2!} = n\cdot(2n-1) = 2n^2 - n$

Now it's your turn for RHS…

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a combinatorial proof:

Suppose you list the first $2n$ integers on a paper and you want to pick $2$ of them. One way to do this is to take two right away from the $2n$ you have. Another way is you either take 2 from the first $n$ numbers, or 2 from the second $n$ numbers, or $1$ from the first $n$ and $1$ from the second $n$ numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Both sides are quadratic polynomials in $n$.
So it suffices to test the equality for three different values of $n$.